# Am I displaying iAd correctly?

Tags: swift, iad

I have the following code in the viewDidLoad()section of my app.

```
func loadAds() {

theAdBanner.delegate = self
theAdBanner.hidden = false
theAdBanner.canDisplayAds = true
view.addSubview(theAdBanner)

}
```

I am only getting one ad that is in blue and it says "You're Connected To iAd". I want to make sure I'm doing this correctly. Why am I only getting one ad? Shouldn't there be more ads loading up, like the ones I see in other apps?

Comment: If the ad is displaying in the place you want it to and it says "You're connected to iAd, then you have implemented it correctly. Its not clear what your problem is.

Comment: Why is only one same ad showing up, why not other ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After implementing iAD if it says "You're Connected To iAd". It means that you implement it correctly, when the app is in the App Store it will appear real Ads.

Just make sure you have all the tax and ads agreements signed.